# Regex - why empty parenthesis?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex to update and there is an empty parenthesis in it. And i wondering : what is the purpose ? I don't find something about it.

The regex :

```
(DE)()([0-9]{1,12})
```

Because, if it is useless, i can remove it.

Comment: It doesn't match anything, but it will count as a capture group.

Comment: People make mistakes all the time. Where did you find this regex? Personally, I think it's useless.

Comment: To expound a bit on @OrangeDog's comment, it's a rather hackish way to get other capture groups to line up with other regexes that may be used which actually capture information there.

Comment: This regex is in my professional application source code, but i can't talk to the original writer of this :)

Comment: Check your version control system for the history of the line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe (and only maybe) the other code uses the capturing groups by their numbers.

It happened to me that I changed one regex changing the parenthesis so the matching groups were changed as well and the rest of the code stopped working because depended on the number of the matching groups.

I recommend you to verify if this is your case before removing the parenthesis.

Answer (score 6):

There is one possible application for empty parentheses that I'm aware of, and that is if you plan to use a regex to determine if a certain string matches a permutation of sub-regexes.

For example,

```
^(?:A()|B()|C()){3}\1\2\3$
```

[will match `ABC` or `CBA` or `BCA` but not `AAA` or `BCC` etc](http://regex101.com/r/tP7lX6/1).

But it doesn't look like that's what the author of your regex was going for.

Comment: @Bergi: According to Jan Goyvaerts, this should work at least in Java, .NET, PCRE, Perl, Ruby and Python. JavaScript won't work because `\1` also matches there if the first capturing group hasn't participated in the match at all. Reference: [Regular Expressions Cookbook, 2nd ed.](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920023630.do), p. 302-5.